# Web Dev Easy: Adding A Web Page

Tags: web-services, web, github-pages

so I'm currently hosting my first website through GitHub pages and hosting it by purchasing a domain on Gandi.net. I'm trying to add to my website for example

website.com/about-me

How do I add the about-me part of it? I guess expand my website so other links can work as well..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As is, your question is a bit too broad/vague to receive a helpful answer. For example, I cannot tell if you are asking for help about GitHub Pages, or about just how to build a website in general. Try editing your question to be more specific. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

To add `/about-me`, you'll need to add an `about-me.html` or `about-me.markdown` page to your GitHub Pages repository. Add this file and add the following, changing where necessary:

```
---
layout: page
title: About Me
permalink: /about-me/
---

This is my about me page!
```

Once you commit this to your repository, you'll see it at `website.com/about-me/`.